AVX512 duplicate low 256 bits into high 256 bits inside a zmm register
Is there a faster way to duplicate (copy) the low 256 bits of an AVX-512 register into the higher 256 bits than using the _mm512_insertf64x4 instruction?
My current solution is:
__m512d zmm1 = _mm512_load_pd(mem);
zmm1 = _mm512_insertf64x4(zmm1,zmm1,1);

Or, equivalently, is there a faster way to load 256 bits (4 doubles) from memory and store them in both low and high 256 bit lanes of a 512-bit zmm register?

Check _mm512_broadcast_f64x4

@chtz: thanks for the info, but isn't _mm512_broadcast_f64x4 more expensive than _mm512_insertf64x4? The intel intrinsics guide states a latency of 8 for _mm512_broadcast_f64x4 vs 3 for _mm512_insertf64x4

VBROADCASTF64X4 only works with a memory source operand, thus its latency includes load latency from address to data from L1d cache. Do you also need the full 512-bit load result for something else?  If not, just use a broadcast load; it's very efficient.  Intel's intrinsics guide shows the _mm512_insertf64x4(__m512d, __m256d, int) latency and throughput based on the VINSERTF64X4 zmm,  zmm, ymm, i8 form, a shuffle of register operands. There is no separate intrinsic for a memory-source insert so the intrinsics guide doesn't give you that level of detail.

Look at https://uops.info/ to find out what's efficient in asm, then write intrinsics that can compile to that asm.  Remember that C __m512d is a C variable that can get optimized away, not always a register.  Give your C variables meaningful names, not stuff like zmm1.  That's going to get more confusing when you check the asm and the C variable zmm1 is kept in zmm3 at the moment, or whatever.

Even if you do need the other half of your _mm512_load_pd(mem) for something, you might still consider two separate loads, instead of one 512-bit load and shuffling twice.  Or a 512-bit load and a 256-bit broadcast-load of the low half.  If the surrounding code bottlenecks on vector ALU throughput, that's good.  Or a load + vinsert works, too, either are fairly good on Intel or Zen 4.

Thanks so much for the detailed response and information @PeterCordes
